# Ruby Savon : How to get the request text sent to server?

Tags: ruby, savon

Hi I'm using Savon to access some web services.

I'm using this code:

```
client=Savon.client(
    wsdl: "WebService.wsdl",
    env_namespace: "S",
    convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase
)

response=client.call(:send_doc)  do
    message(
      Attr1: "123",
      Attr2: "ABC")
    )
```

How do I get the request text sent to server?

Regards
Fak

Answer (score 3):

[Savon](http://savonrb.com/) 2 provides an [Observer](http://savonrb.com/version2/observers.html) interface. You can register an `Observer` which is notified before the request is send. The interface contains a `Builder` object where you find the XML content of the request. `Builder#pretty()` formats the XML content.

```
class Observer
  def notify(_, builder, _, _)
    puts builder.pretty
    nil
  end
end

Savon.observers << Observer.new
```

Alternativly you can add `log: true` to your client configuration. It enables the logging of the requests.

```
client = Savon.client(log: true, ...)
```

Comment: `log: true` is the easiest solution. Thanks for this! I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with stable versions of Savon. However, you can get the request using version 3 of Savon (see [the Savon website](http://savonrb.com/version3/) for installation instructions and more detail). Example from the site:

```
client = Savon.new('http://example.com?wsdl')
operation = client.operation(service_name, port_name, operation_name)
operation.build # returns SOAP request
```

You could also monkeypatch Savon methods or set up a custom debugger to get this information with your current Savon version. See these StackOverflow answers for more information:

- [Accessing the request body of a SOAP request with Savon (Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619321/accessing-the-request-body-of-a-soap-request-with-savon-ruby-on-rails)
- [View Savon Request XML without Sending to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860045/view-savon-request-xml-without-sending-to-server)